# Delete first line of all files in a folder (on ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, awk, sed, terminal, bioinformatics

I have a folder that has 2800 .txt files in it and I need to delete the first line of every files. The names of the files are all different except for that fact that they end with .txt .

would it be possible to do that while keeping the same file name (instead of sending the output (file without the first line) to another file)...

Comment: something along the line `find /path -name *.txt -exec sed -i '1d' '{}'\;` should do. (do a try on a subset of files in a test directory before)

Answer (score 11):

something like this does the trick

```
sed -i '1d' *.txt
```

where -i is inplace editing

edit: adition

pls try also this

```
time sed -i '1d' *.txt
```

and compare with other solutions (just add time before)[trying certainly with some backup files]

Answer (score 3):

You could do a bash script. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *; 
do 
    tail -n +2 "${filename}"
done
```

The run it from command line: `$ <script_file.sh>`

Take this with a grain of salt. I'm not actually running on a *nix machine. See [here for a variety of ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96226/delete-first-line-of-a-file) of deleting the first line of a file. Also note that `tail` is supposed to be much faster than `sed`, if performance is important to you.

Comment: You're welcome. You don't have enough rep to vote yet but don't forget to accept!

Answer (score 2):

For a small number of files, what I'd write is

```
for f in *.txt; do sed 1d "$f" >tmpfile; mv tmpfile "$f"; done
```

For a large enough number of files, however, that won't work, because the shell will expand the `*.txt` to an argument list which is too long.

In that case (which sounds like your case), a better approach is

```
ls | grep '.txt$' | while read f; do sed 1d "$f" >tmpfile; mv tmpfile "$f"; done
```

You should be aware, however, that there are in-principle problems with this (as @EdMorton stresses in comments on an earlier version of this answer).  One is that this will have trouble if you are unfortunate enough to have a directory whose name ends in `.txt` (you could handle that with `test -f` if you really felt the need). The other is that the `read` could have problems if there are some odd characters (such as a `\n`, say, or one or other type of quotes) in one of the filenames. You can handle such things by fiddling with `IFS` (see the comments), but it's better to have a quick glance at the files you're working on, and fix such bad filenames first.

What you shouldn't do is `ls *.txt | ...`, since if the number of files is long enough that `for f in *.txt; do ...` won't work, then `ls *.txt` won't work either.

---

There are more elaborate things you can do.

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt | while read f; do ...
```

That selects specifically files ending in `.txt`, but I always find the options to `file` untidy to type or read, and feel `ls`+`grep` is neater here.

Another possibility is

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -exec sed -i 1d '{}' \;
```

That's pretty robust, but like most non-trivial `file` commands, it ends up looking like a mess, and you have to have memorised `find`'s non-obvious syntax.  Also **that won't work unless your `sed` supports a no-argument `-i` option** (POSIX `sed` doesn't have `-i`, and the `sed` on OS X and other BSDs effectively requires an extension to be specified).  Also, this approach is limited to a single command, so won't work in a case where you need do to more to the files.

Comment: That will fail in many interesting ways given various file names. Don't do it. google parsing ls, quoting shell variables, don't write shell loops, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, of course it's not robust against semi-pathological file names (which includes file names with spaces in many cases), and I almost certainly wouldn't write this in a script that was going to run un-watched, but given that I can first glance at the list of files I want to process, that's what I'd regard as good enough.  That said, quoting the `$f` is a good reflex to have, and not doing it a bit sloppy, so I'll edit the answer to put those in.

Comment: It's shell fundamentals - don't parse the output of ls, always quote your variables unless you have a very specific purpose in mind and fully understand the effects, and always write read commands using `IFS=` and `-r` (e.g. `while IFS= read -r f`) again unless you have a very specific purpose in mind and fully understand the effects.It's extremely easy to do it the right way following those fundamental rules so why do it the wrong way and then say "because it's good enough".

Comment: @EdMorton I realised that `ls *.txt` fails when there are too many such files (doh!), so rewritten. I've only mentioned `IFS` in passing, because this is shell syntax arcana, not fundamentals. Expertise is knowing when 'good enough' is good enough, and when it isn't.